# Retrieving property from DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, methods, properties, prototype

I recently started diving into self-instantiating classes in javascript. While I can get an entire DOM element with no problem, I'm not able to access any properties of the element from outside the class.
HTML:

```
<div id="thisDiv"></div>
```

Class:

```
(function () {  
   function getDiv (el) {
     this.el = el;
  }

  var get = function getTheDiv (el) {
    return this.el;
  }
})();
```

*Works -* Retrieve entire element with jQuery:

```
var g = $('#thisDiv').get();  
console.log(g);
```

and I get the DOM object. But

```
var g = $('#thisDiv').get();  
console.log(g.id);
```

returns `undefined`

I feel that it has to be an issue with the scope and making the properties public, but I just can't quite get it.

Comment: where does the g() method come from? does g[0].id work?

Comment: +1 to @dandavis on this, you need to post the definition of `g`. There are some obvious problems related to scope, but it's not possible to give you a complete answer without more information

Comment: Perfect, yes, my definition was not correct, I was setting the prototype method name to 'get', not 'g'. Updated.

Comment: And yes, setting my array to 0 lets me access the id property @dandavis. Why is this? I never defined an array or looped...

Comment: i suspected as much; you are returning a jQuery collection, not an element.

Comment: Ah ha. Absolutely. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your "*Class:*" code does not make any sense. Please explain what is supposed to do, or post your whole, real code (or a working, meaningful subset)

Comment: @Bergi, the "Class:" code is an extremely basic js library returning the value of the element called. My problem was that jQuery returns a collection, and I was trying to access it as an individual element, as commented by dandavis.

Comment: @erikjwright: The code you posted is not a library, but a no-op (it does *nothing*). Did you mean to return the `getDiv` function as a constructor, and assign it to `$`?

Comment: Certainly a no-op. I'm trying to grasp the modular philosophy of javascript libs, so excuse my remiss. I am trying to use getDiv as a constructor, then create methods accessible from outside the script.